# Download file from dropbox failing when name contains spaces

Tags: c#, encoding, dropbox

I am trying to download a file from dropbox using the RESTful API. When I encounter a file that has a space in it "My Photo.png" the program stops on `var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(requestUri);` It returns a 403 error. If I remove the spaces and try the file download again it works perfectly. Ive checked the formatted uri and it is being returned as "My+Photo.png" is this how it should be? What am I doing wrong?

```
    var uri = new Uri(new Uri(DropboxRestApi.ApiContentServer),
        String.Format("files?root={0}&path={1}",
        root, UpperCaseUrlEncode(path)));
```

My Method:

```
    private static string UpperCaseUrlEncode(string s)
    {
        char[] temp = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(s).ToCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < temp.Length - 2; i++)
        {
            if (temp[i] == '%')
            {
                temp[i + 1] = char.ToUpper(temp[i + 1]);
                temp[i + 2] = char.ToUpper(temp[i + 2]);
            }
        }
        return new string(temp);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you do the normal URLEncode and do a string.Replace on the temp string it will work perfect for files with a space in the file name

```
temp = temp.Replace("+", "%20");
```